# Can I make a 32-bit program with cx_Freeze if I have a 64-bit OS?

Tags: python, 64-bit, 32-bit, cx-freeze

I am currently running Windows 7 Home 64-bit and am working on a program that I would like to make available for both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows operating systems. When I use cx_Freeze to turn my .py to a .exe, it only allows it to be installed on 64-bit operating systems.

Would I need to buy a 32-bit computer to convert it to a 32-bit program or are there a special set of commands I can use to make cx_Freeze create both a 32-bit and a 64-bit exe?

```
from cx_Freeze import *
import sys

base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = "Win32GUI"

executables = [Executable("iNTMI.py", shortcutName = "iNTMI", shortcutDir = "DesktopFolder", base = base, icon = "C:/Program Files/iNTMI/assets/images/programIcon.ico")]

setup(
    name = "iNTMI",                                            
    options = {"build_exe": {"packages": ["tkinter", "minecraftItems", "ProgFunctions", "minecraftItems"], "include_files": ["ProgFunctions.py", "minecraftItems.py"]}},
    executables = executables
    )
```

Comment: if you install 32 bit python and use only 32 bit libraries you can `freeze` it and have it work on both 32 bit and 64 bit versions of windows. the reason you get this error is you have installed the 64 bit version of python.

Comment: @JamesKent That actually makes a lot of sense. Thank you! If I revert to a 32 bit Python, will I have to redownload all my modules again? (cx_freeze, pillow, etc)?

Comment: it depends on how you are installing them, if you're installing from source then usually no, but most modules that can be installed with `.exe` or `.msi` files would have to be re downloaded, but the advantage (in this case) of using 32 bit python is that one build works on both (assuming you don't need a big amount of memory or other 64bit extras)

Comment: Certain ones I have installed by using the .whl files and others I have done with .exe/.msi. Will the .whl modules need to be replaced as well?

Comment: i haven't used that many `.whl` files, so i'm not certain, i think it depends on how the module is built, if it's pure python then it should be file, but if it contains C extension code then it may not. you'll probably have to just try it and see

Comment: Yes, you'll definitely need to download new versions of any modules with compiled code, which includes cx_Freeze and pillow. If you're using pip, it will be easiest just to install all the modules you need again.

Answer (score 5):

No you do not need to buy another PC (thankfully) and no theirs no command for it either.  If you want a 32bit .exe you just need an x32 bit Python installation and freeze it in the normal way and you will have a x32 executable.  This will work on both x32 and x64 computers.

Since you are running x64 installation you can also create x64 .exe and have both x32 (if you get a x32 bit installation) and x64 .exe.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a virtual machine with Windows 10 32 bit and you can install Python on the machine and it works.

If you can't run a virtual machine there are lot of tutorials online.