# is it possible to run both python 32bits and 64 bits on the same computer? and how to distinguish between them when calling python in terminal?

Tags: python, tkinter, pip, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

so i've just made my first serious real program in python(64 bits) and i turned it into an exe using cx_Freeze since i had some issues with pyinstaller . To resume the issue i had with distributing my exe some of my friends are 32 bits and i've read somewhere that in order to create a 32 bit version of my program i had to install a 32 bit of python in my computer(64 bits) but i don t know how to procede with that. Did anyone run into an issue similar to this ? and please how can i use both versions in my computer and distinguish between them .
btw in my python code i m only using tkinter so i guess if i installed a 32 bit version of python i need to reinstall tkinter with it , but idk how to tell cmd that  i want to use the 32 bit python and not the 64 bit one.

Comment: 32 bit `exe`s can run on 64 bit computers so why not just compile it as a 32 bit `exe`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple Python versions on the same machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547554/multiple-python-versions-on-the-same-machine)

Comment: Please also see [Can I make a 32-bit program with cx_Freeze if I have a 64-bit OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31516951/8516269)